# Indentation issue in the pull request

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

I am a beginner in Git and GitHub.
There's an issue that I am facing.

I made changes in a separate branch and pushed them, but when I looked into the "Files Changed" section on GitHub, there were unnecessary indentations that weren't present in my editor (Atom).

Can anyone explain me why is it happening and what's the solution for this?

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to the Stacks, Azan.  Edit your question to add the `atom-editor` tag.

Answer (score 1):

This isn‘t a Github or Git problem. That has to do with the text editor, in your case with *atom* and your coding style. Use either **only** tabs or **only** spaces for indentation.

If you use a tab in your code and your text editor *atom* shows a tab, as an example. as 2 spaces, it is still passing `\t` and not `\s\s` in your code. And tabs can display different on all platforms. So your text editor *atom* makes 2 spaces for one tab, and GitHub display tabs as 8 spaces. That‘s why looking different.

But you can configure your editor to insert either a literal tab character or some number of spaces, when you hit the tab key.

How you can change the indentation, you can look at this [stackoverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608160/how-to-change-indentation-mode-in-atom)

Comment: You can also change the way GitHub shows tabs in the diff by adding e.g. `?ts=2` to the diff URL https://stackoverflow.com/a/23522945/2066474